# How can I post my value from a selectform without using Dropdownlistfor in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I don't know how much code is needed in order for you to understand my problem so I'm starting with explaining what I want to do.
I have a form in my View where I create a new object. 
In this form I want to use a dropdownlist and I've tried a lot with @Html.Dropdownlistfor() but realized I don't want to use that since I don't know how to use som Jquery UI-code on this and I don't know how to send a different value than what is shown in the dropdownlist.
Does any of you know how i just send the value selected in the dropdownlist to my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropDownListFor` helper method esssentially render a `SELECT` element. So if you do not want to use the helper method, You may write the RAW HTML code

```
@model CreateUserVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <select name="SelectedCity" id="SelectedCity">
      <option value='1'>Ann Arbor</option>
      <option value='2'>Novi</option>
      <option value='3'>Detroit</option>
    </select>
}
```

Make sure your SELECT elements name property value is same as what you use in your Model, so that Model binding will work.

```
public class CreateUserVM
{
   public int SelectedCity { set;get;}
  //other properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In view model:

```
puclic class ViewModel
{
   int SelectId{get;set;}
}
```

In view

```
<select name="SelectId" id="SelectId">
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
```

After post form ViewModel.SelectId will contain value of selected item in dropdown